# How do i return data where that contain empty string instead of NULL in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to get my data from database where one of my attribute was empty string instead of null....but my code return all data where NULL and empty string combined...here is my code

```
public function findAllPersons2(){
        return $this->where('pi_person_type','3')
                     ->where('pi_vendor_id','!=' , '')
                    ->orderBy('pi_name', 'asc')
                    ->get();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code are using an not equal to an empty string condition. To retrieve all persons where pi_vendor_id's is empty, do the following where condition.

```
->where('pi_vendor_id', '=', '')
```

Comment: Hi...i already try but more worse it does not return anything of my data

Comment: Have you tried removing where('pi_person_type','3') to see if it returns data then? and are you sure that the field is actually empty?

Comment: my bad sir i call wrong attribute actually ...thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Try as below.

```
$this->where('pi_person_type','3')
                     ->where(function($q){
                         $q->whereNull('pi_vendor_id')->orwhere('pi_vendor_id','');
                     })

                    ->orderBy('pi_name', 'asc')
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will also work:

```
->where('pi_vendor_id', '')
```

> For convenience, if you want to verify that a column is equal to a
>   given value, you may pass the value directly as the second argument to
>   the where method.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#where-clauses